Finding the coordinates related to the standard basis when given the coordinates relative to a different basis
The problem:
Find the coordinates of the vector $A$ related to the standard basis for $M_2(\mathbb{R}) $ if it has the coordinates $(1, -1, 3, 2)$ relative to the basis
$B = \left\{ E_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, E_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, E_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, E_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \subseteq M_2(\mathbb{R}).
$
Using the Transition Matrix Method,
$[A]_B = T_{BBs} * [A]_{Bs}$
I found:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\-1 \\3 \\2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  * \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d 
\end{bmatrix}=> a=2; b=1; c=-4; d=2 => [A]_{Bs}=(2,1,-4,2)
\\
$$
But this is not the same answer as in the textbook. What is the error? Am I not understanding the question or have I solved it incorrectly?

There is no need to use transition matrices here. Just use the definition of coordinates with respect to a basis.
By definition, $A$ has coordinates $(\color{red}{1,-1,3,2})$ with respect to the basis $\{E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\}$ means that
$$ A = \color{red}{1} E_1 +(\color{red}{-1}) E_2 + \color{red}{3} E_3 + \color{red}{2}E_4.$$
You only need to compute this sum to get a two by two matrix. Then you can directly read the coordinates with respect to the standard basis inside of said matrix.

You flipped the formula. If the coordinates in standard basis are $(a,b,c,d)$, then
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \\c\\d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1\\
3 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5\\3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
Hope this helps. :)
